# Possible orders of elements of the symmetric group $S_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups

> Consider the symmetric group $S_{10}$. List all possible orders of the elements of this group and provide examples of elements of each order.

Attempt: the order of an element in the symmetric group is the lcm of the cycle lengths in writing that elements as disjoint cycles. So I believe we need to enumerate the ways of writing $10$ as a sum of natural numbers. For instance, we have $10=3+2+5$, so as the lcm is $30$ we could have an element of order $30$, an example being $(1\ 2\ 3)(4\ 5)(6\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10)$. Is this right? Even still, I'm not sure how to answer this question 'nicely' without a great deal of calculation and mess on the page. I want my solution to be neat.

Comment: With regard to your subquestion 'Is this right?' Yes. This way you get all orders and no non-orders. Unfortunately I do not know the answer to the other question, if there is a nicer way. I hope someone else can answer that.

Comment: There are 42 partitions of 10: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function going through all of them is not *too* bad.

Comment: To determine the maximal order of an element in a symmetric group (the value of [Landau's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function)) would solve the Riemann Hypotesis, so it must be very hard to list all the possible orders of the elements of $S_n$ in general. Unless there is something really nice about $10$, I would guess your best shot is really to deal with the calculations.

Comment: You could recursively calculate the set of possible orders for each $n$ -- along the lines of $f(n) = \bigcup_{k=1}^n \{ \operatorname{lcm}(k, o) \mid o \in f(n-k) \}$.  That would give a bit of an advantage in collapsing partitions which give the same order at each stage.  (Just be sure if you're writing a program to do this calculation, that $f$ should be memoized, or alternately use dynamic programming to calculate the sets, to avoid duplication of effort.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from a standpoint of what has to be done,  you simply need the set of all $\rm{lcm}'$s of *partitions* of $10$, in this case.   So there's in a sense a nice neat solution.  Tedious is the particulars. I'm not going to endeavor to do that here.

Ramanujan was into partitions.   I've heard the foremost authority now is George Andrews at Penn State.  There's a function that counts the number of partitions of $n$, but it's I think difficult.

According to a comment solving this problem in general would solve the Riemann hypothesis.   So watch out!

---

For getting started:  $10=2+2+2+2+2$ gives us an element of order $\rm{lcm}(2,2,2,2,2)=2$.  Or, $10=2+3+5$ gives an element of order $\rm{lcm}(2,3,5)=30$.  $10=5+5$ gives $\rm {lcm}(5,5)=5$.  Etc...  So there's apparently $37$ more to check (according to the comments).

And it's easy also to provide elements of those orders:  $$(12)(34)(56)(78)(9\,10),(12)(345)(6789\,10),(12345)(6789\,10)$$, respectively.